# How to merge multiple m4a or audio files and attach it to audio tag, and show the time on controller correctly

Tags: javascript

```
<audio id="audio" controls>
    <source src="Countdown.m4a" type="audio/x-m4a">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

This is the html element, I want to repeat "Countdown.m4a" three times, and as "Countdown.m4a" is 5 mins longer, the controller slider should show 15 mins instead of 5 mins.

How to achieve this?

tried using , but not able to modify control slider length.
Tried finding how we can merge the files using js, but nothing I could find online.

Answer (score 0):

Because all a/v media is inherently more complex and involved than it seems (meaning concatenating media is more problematic than you might think for a whole bunch of reasons), your best bet would be to concatenate sound by doing all your work server side, where you can leverage command line apps like ffmpeg.

That said, check this out: https://mitya.uk/articles/concatenating-audio-pure-javascript, which has a refreshingly thorough client side approach.